# JHipster - cant add jquery path in angular.json

Tags: jquery, angular, sass, compilation, jhipster

Normaly it is really easy to add `SCSS` styles and `jQuery` path to angular project, we just have to add it on script : [] section,

However :

Checking the `angular.js` generated from `jhipster`, I can see the architect part is empty:

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "consuldent": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src/main/webapp",
            "projectType": "application",
            "architect": {}
        }
    },
</i>
```

Adding path to my `index.html` work for me but I want to know if there is another method.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Have you read the example about leaflet in your project's README.md? Adding to index.html will work only in dev but not in webpack prod build.

Comment: did you found any solution for this question ? i have the same problem and i need a solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for "how to add `jquery` in `jhipster`" (version `angular`) :

```
 npm install --save --save-exact jquery
 npm install --save-dev --save-exact @types/jquery
```

and in your `vendor.ts` (location :  `src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts` ) and add :

```
....
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.js';
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';
....
```

then add this in your component ( just next imports) where you want to use `jquery` :

```
....
import * as $ from 'jquery';
....
```

and in your `ngOnInit` function :

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    $(()=>{
      $('#id').codejs....;
    });
  }
```